Free objects in the category of rngs
I realize I still don't fully understand the process of constructing free objects in general. In this wikipage, the last paragraph states the "free rng generated by a set $\{x\}$ is the ring of all integral polynomials over $x$ with no constant terms". I suppose they are talking about univariate polynomials, and

if the set $X:=\{x_i:i\in I\}$ is not singleton, then is the free rng all integral multivariate polynomials without constant terms? Is it correct to first construct the free semigroup $FS(X)$ of multiplication over set $X$, then construct the free abelian group $F_{ab}FS(X)$, over set $FS(X)$?

Is there a reference, such as a textbook, for a definitive statement? I can understand things in terms of universal properties, but not always capable of proving a construction is correct. Thanks in advance.

Do you assume commutativity in polynomials? In rngs?

@Trebor No commutativity is assumed. Maybe I shouldn't call it polynomials, but words?

Incidentally, it looks like it might be a bit tricky to show associativity of the multiplication.  For example, you have $(a+ab)(bc+c)=2abc + ac + a b^2 c$ involves collecting terms that happened to agree, and if you then want to check $[(a+ab)(bc+c)]x = (a+ab)[(bc+c)x]$ for some other $x$, you have to contend with the fact you did a certain collection on one side but not the other.

OK, I guess the version of van der Waerden's trick for this case would be: for each $i \in I$, left multiplication by $x_i$ induces a set map $FS(X) \to FS(X)$, and thus an endomorphism of the abelian group $F_{ab} FS(X)$.  And for nonempty $I$, each element of $F_{ab}FS(X)$ induces a different endomorphism since you can recover it from what it does on $x_{i_0}$ for some $i_0 \in I$.  So, you get an injective map from $F_{ab}FS(X)$ to the endomorphism r(i)ng.  (And an easier proof holds in case $I = \emptyset$ -- you just get the zero rng.)


if the set $X:=\{x_i:i\in I\}$ is not singleton, then is the free rng all integral multivariate polynomials without constant terms?

Yes, provided either that you work with commutative rngs or that by "polynomial" you mean noncommutative polynomial (or word).

Is it correct to first construct the free semigroup $FS(X)$ of multiplication over set $X$, then construct the free abelian group $F_{ab}FS(X)$, over set $FS(X)$?

Yes, that's correct. The abstract way to see this is to think of the free rng as the left adjoint of the forgetful functor $\text{Rng} \to \text{Set}$, use the fact that adjoints compose (the left adjoint of $F \circ G$ is $G^L \circ F^L$ where $L$ denotes the left adjoint), and factor the forgetful functor as a composition of forgetful functors
$$\text{Rng} \to \text{SemiGrp} \to \text{Set}$$
where the first functor takes the underlying multiplicative semigroup. This factors the left adjoint as a composition of free functors $\text{Set} \to \text{SemiGrp} \to \text{Rng}$, namely: first we take the free semigroup on a set $X$, then we take the "semigroup ring" of this thing. In this approach nearly all of the work goes into proving that the left adjoint of the forgetful functor $\text{Rng} \to \text{SemiGrp}$ is given by taking the semigroup ring (which is the obvious thing if you're familiar with group and monoid rings).
The same remarks apply with $\text{Rng}$ replaced by $\text{Ring}$ and $\text{SemiGrp}$ replaced by $\text{Mon}$; to construct free rings you take the free monoid, then the monoid ring (which produces noncommutative polynomials). Similarly with commutative rings and commutative monoids where you take the free commutative monoid, which produces ordinary polynomials.
